# Use UWP UI in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I have an application which runs in the background, but i wanted to add a Window with the UWP API.

After adding the References to:

```
Windows.UI
Windows.UI.Xaml
```

I tried to start the UWP application with:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(p => new UWPApp(); );
```

In the UWPApp class i added the UWP template code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace ClipboardSync {

    public class UWPApp : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application {

        private bool _contentLoaded;

        public void InitializeComponent() {
            if (_contentLoaded)
                return;

            _contentLoaded = true;
        }

        public UWPApp() {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }


        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null) {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated) {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false) {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null) {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e) {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }

    }  

}
```

but the new UWPApp Instance is never created and there is no error message.

Is there some kind of restriction so that I can't start a UWP Application inside a WPF App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1/31/2019**
Coming back to this to update my answer. As of Windows 10 update 1809 (build 17763+) this is now supported. More information and samples here:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/11/02/xaml-islands-a-deep-dive-part-1/

**Old answer - pre-1809**
This is not supported today. Windows.UI.XAML.* can currently only be used in UWP app processes.

However, at BUILD2017 earlier this year it was announced that support for this is planned in a future update of Windows 10:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8100