# Using flyout controls in wpf

Tags: wpf

I would like to use the flyout controls in my project.

When I tried to use them, I found that it wasn't working

(I guess I'm probably missing some using...)

What should I do so I can use the flyout controls?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <MenuFlyout>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Share" >
        <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE72D;" />
        </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
    </MenuFlyoutItem>
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" Icon="Copy" />
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Icon="Delete" />
    <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rename" />
    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Select" />
    </MenuFlyout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "Wasn't working" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens?

Comment: Error message. He doesn't recognize it...
(Sorry I forgot to mention it ...)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use UWP controls in WPF. WPF doesn't have these.

Comment: I have heard that they can also be used in WPF. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Should edit question to include additional info - the exact error message.

Comment: looks like it's currently not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010492/